# Resample a pandas timeseries by "1st Monday of month" etc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (daily) pandas timeSeries that I need to filter down to monthly, using the nth occurrence of a particular weekday as the rule for selecting dates

My thinking so far is the best way to do this would be to first make a list or Series of all the dates that I'm interested in, and then asking the timeseries for those dates?

But that still leaves the question of how do I make a list of e.g. all "2nd Tuesday of the Month"s that have happened between two dates?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lets take for example September and October 2014:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime(2014, 9, 1)
end = datetime(2014, 10, 30)
d = pd.date_range(start, end) # use bdate_range for business days
```

Now you can build a mask containing only the dates you are interested in:

```
>>> mask = (d.weekday == 1) & (7 < d.day) & (d.day < 15)
>>> d[mask]

<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2014-09-09, 2014-10-14]
Length: 2, Freq: None, Timezone: None
```

Comment: Accepted this solution in the end, both were good, but this seemed like it would be easier for someone reading the code to see what was going on.

Answer (score 1):

Some dummy data:

```
In [44]: df = pd.DataFrame(data=range(1000), index=pd.date_range('1999-01-01', periods=1000), columns=['value'])
```

Let's assume you want the 2nd Tuesday of each month.  You can resample to a particular day of the week, using a built-in pandas offset

```
In [45]: df = df.resample('W-TUE', how='last')
```

Then, you can calculate a week of month column, and use that to filter.

```
In [50]: df['wom'] = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('M'))['value'].transform(lambda x: range(len(x))) + 1

In [53]: df[df['wom'] == 2].head()
Out[53]: 
            value  wom
1999-01-12     11    2
1999-02-09     39    2
1999-03-09     67    2
1999-04-13    102    2
1999-05-11    130    2
```